# Will there be a second chance for salvation after the Rapture?

Tags: eschatology

Does the Bible say anything about there being a second chance for salvation after the time of rapture? I would assume that God is doing this rapture so that people would recognize Him and repent. But I don't have a Biblical basis for my assumptions.

Comment: As written, this question sounds a lot like a truth question. 'Biblical basis' is insufficient to rescue the inherent lack of scope that arises from not specifying an eschatological (or other appropriately definitive) doctrinal framework.

Answer (score 14):

For starters, the Bible doesn't contain the word "rapture" nor does it clearly state that such an event will happen. Different people have read between the lines to infer a rapture at different points in the book of Revelation, but it is not clearly stated anywhere.

Since the Bible doesn't clearly state that there will be a Rapture and those who believe that it **will** happen disagree significantly on **when** it will happen, the only clear answer that can be given to your question is:

"No, the Bible does not make a clear statement about there being a second chance for salvation after the time of rapture."

Comment: +1. This is pretty much exactly what I was going to write, but you beat me to it.

Comment: `Re: nor does it clearly state that such an event will happen` - "Keep awake then and watch at all times [be discreet, attentive, and ready], praying that you may have the full strength and ability and be accounted worthy to `escape` all these things [taken together] that will take place, and to stand in the presence of the Son of Man." Luke 21:36 (AMP)

Comment: @jimreed The word rapture comes from the Latin translation of "caught up" in 1 Thes. 4:17: "Then we who are alive and remain shall be caught up together to meet the Lord in the air. And thus we shall always be with the Lord." Jesus is alluding to the "caught up" in Mark 13:27 when the angels gather the elect around the time of the tribulation period. And 1 Cor. 15:51 tells us of the mystery that we shall not all die, but we shall all be changed in a moment, in the twinkling of an eye. So the Bible does speak of this event, and the term Rapture is given the name of the concept.

Answer (score 0):

However it does state that we will be caught up with Him and He will return (1 Thes. 4:17).

Also if there was a second chance He would have to go back to the beginning of time and give everyone a second chance.

Now do you think that he will allow those who chose  Hell for not believing in Christ to change their mind?  No He won't you make your choice while you are here and when He does return it will be too late to make that choice

Comment: Where does it say this?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. Can you please cite your sources for the passage as well as reference what Christian tradition interprets it like this? You might want to check out some of our meta posts on site guidelines such as [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692)

Comment: This is true.

The word rapture came into use because of the phrase in the [latin vulgate](http://www.latinvulgate.com/lv/verse.aspx?t=1&b=13&c=4) translation in 1 Thessalonians 4  "simul **rapiemur** cum illis in nubibus" (will be **caught up** with them in clouds).

In Engish we have used "rapture" in place of "rapiermur".

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. On this site, we're not looking for personal interpretation, but rather focusing on what various Christian groups teach.  See [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If the Rapture takes place in [Revelation 7:9-17](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rev&c=7&t=KJV#s=1174009) according to the Pre-wrth Rapture viewpoint, then there will be no further salvation. The Pre-wrath Rapture takes away the remaining saved; what's left is God's wrath in the trumpet and the bowl judgments. (That's why it's called the "Pre-wrath" Rapture.)

During those judgments, it never tells us of people repenting. Rather, they "will desire to die" ([9:6](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rev&c=9&t=KJV#s=1176006)); "they did not repent" ([9:21](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rev&c=9&t=KJV#s=1176021)); "blasphemed the name of God" ([16:9](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rev&c=16&t=KJV#s=1183009)); "blasphemed the God of heaven" ([16:11](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rev&c=16&t=KJV#s=1183011)); and gathered "them to the battle of that great day of God Almighty" ([16:14](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rev&c=16&t=KJV#s=1183014)). So the Bible gives us a dim view of the possibility of salvation when He pours out His wrath. What's left of humanity after the Rapture will receive His "true and righteous ... judgments" ([16:7](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rev&c=16&t=KJV#s=1183007)).