# What about those who lived before Christ long outside the reach of Israel?

Tags: bible, soteriology, old-testament, israel

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What happens to people who have never heard about Jesus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/what-happens-to-people-who-have-never-heard-about-jesus)
>   [Who saved people before ~33AD?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1824/30)
>   [Do I get a second chance to believe in Jesus after I die?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1775/30)
>   [Were there provisions for salvation for non-Jews in the OT?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3999/30)

You know, there's always the question about what happens to those that have not heard the gospel and therefore can neither accept nor decline the offer of God. Some say that they get a chance somehow and that Jesus may show himeself to them, and Paul writes something along the lines that some fulfill the requirements of the law by their heart (if I remember it correctly). I don't know what God's plan is for them, but I think that a sligtly bigger and more interesting question, is **what happened to those that lived before Christ and long outside the reach of Israel**?

I guess you can say that one of God's plans for Israel, is that it should present God to the world. Those who lived close to Israel and could see Israel and the works of God in that land could choose whether to accept that, but those who lived far away from it didn't have that choice. Take, for instance, the aborigines of Australia or the Inuits of North America. Did they have any chance for salvation?

I talked to my wife about this and she said that she had heard that -- but this could as likely be wishful preaching -- Jesus went down to realm of death and gave them a choice to follow him, or something like that. I failed to find a passage in the Bible giving an account for this, but it seems kind of plausible to me.